# Configure Tabs with Buttons in react-navigation?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

This may not be possible in react-navigation. But asking, just in case, there are some work-arounds or ways which I am not aware of.

[image]

In the above screenshot, I have two tabs - Trending and Watchlist. And on the right corner, are two buttons - search icon and filter icon to do some actions.

Is this kind of tabbed layout possible with react-navigation? Is this possible using Android SDK (Java code)? If possible, I like to know how (at high level).

Comment: Have you tried using [`tabBarComponent`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#TabNavigatorConfig)? See [this similar issue in the Github](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2601) for a discussion on this topic.

Comment: @MichaelCheng Thanks, It is an option to replace TabBarBottom or TabBarTop with my own custom component. It looks a bit intimidating when I look at the code within react-navigation. There are so many subtle animations all over the code. Writing all of it from scratch will be quite a task!